# Can Nginx proxy a specific URL to conceal the directory of a script file?

Tags: nginx, matomo

I would like to use Matomo (self-hosted tracking software, similar to Google Analytics). The JS snippet exposes a PHP file which is called for tracking (see [here](https://developer.matomo.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide) for example). This PHP file is in the same folder as the file for login and others, i.e. this exposes too much information for malicious crawlers. Therefore I would like to proxy the URL to the PHP file via an non-existing or misleading path. E.g.

Unsecure:

```
_paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'https://www.mytracker.com/exposed_installation/matomo.php']);
```

Should become something more secure:

```
_paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'https://www.mytracker.com/non-existing-path/matomo.php']);
```

So this way a crawler could only see the tracking script file, but everything else would lead to a 404.

Would that be possible? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Why not using [recommanded nginx configuration](https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/matomo.conf) ?

Comment: I'm gonna be mean. I see two questions in your post. Both can be answered with yes.

Comment: @Yanis-git Thanks. As far as I can judge it this only protects internal files, but still allows crawlers to see the login page etc, see `location ~ ^/(index|matomo|piwik|js/index|plugins/HeatmapSessionRecording/configs)\.php {`

Comment: @qräbnö Well, then I'm gonna be mean as well and invite you to answer both.

Answer (score 1):

Please try Matomo Tracker Proxy https://github.com/matomo-org/tracker-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Untested.

```
location ~ ^/external/matomo\.php$
{
    …
}

location ~ ^/hidden_blablahblahblablubb/(?:index|matomo|piwik|js/index|plugins/HeatmapSessionRecording/configs)\.php$
{
    …
}
```

If `matomo.php` needs other files, you can work with more (named) `location`s and maybe the Nginx location command `internal` in combination with `rewrite`.